# create fileno on class?

Tags: python, sockets

I am currently re-writing some code that uses python's `select.select()` method, but these will only return socket objects in which I have to go and manually match that socket to the socket in a class that was put in there under `__init__`. the pseudo-code for that would basically be `[classobject for classobject in classList if SocketFromSelection == class.socketobject][0]` (which I'm pretty much using).

I found in python documentation that in `select.select()`, "You may also define a wrapper class yourself, as long as it has an appropriate fileno() method (that really returns a file descriptor, not just a random integer)."

My question is, how would I attach a fileno() method in a class so that I can pass a sequence of these classes into `select.select()` so that it returns the classes and not just the sockets? Also, would this run on windows? If not, is there a better way to match the socket to the socket in a class in a list of classes?

Comment: As long as you define `fileno` to return the real `fileno` of what it's wrapping, all will be well. Maybe not on Windows, though ;).

Comment: yeah, but if I have `def fileno():` in my class, what variable can give me that class's file descriptor required?

Comment: It has to be the `fileno` of whatever you're wrapping, so `def fileno(self): return self.thing_you_are_wrapping.fileno()`.

Comment: I'm trying to wrapp the class, but I don't think putting this in the class would accomplish it: `def fileno(self): return self.fileno()`.

Comment: If you're wrapping a class, try `super().fileno()` (Python 3). You're not being very clear here.

Comment: In a nutshell, trying to make a python class something that I can take and put into a sequence that would work with `select.select()` by giving it a `fileno()` method. I'm not sure where to put that code either.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it's not wrapping an open file or socket? It's impossible unless you use a temporary file or socket, you can't just use an arbitrary non-file. If you're wrapping a file or socket should delegate the call, but if not you can't use `select.select`. // You can try faking it with a temporary file (Python has modules for that) but you're making it hard on yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you included in your question, it sounds like you have a class that contains a socket inside of it (as the `socketobject` attribute). In this case, you can make your wrapper object `select`able by proxying the socket's `fileno` method on your wrapper:

```
def SocketWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socketobj = socket # use whatever you are already doing

    def fileno(self):
        return self.socketobj.fileno()
```

Now you can pass instances of `SocketWrapper` directly to `select`, rather than passing the sockets and then later having to sort out which socket corresponds to which instance.